# how to save 5 words in one word using python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

for example I want to save inevitable, unavoidable, certain, sure = "necessary" if mentioned words are using in my giving sentence, so my program automatically change these words into "necessary" and give me sentence
for example
it is inevitable or unavoidable or certain or sure, that person age should be 18
so my python program automatically detect these words and convert in to
"it is necessary that person age should be 18"

Comment: Post your code with problems or where you did reached, dont ask "how to..."

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't very clear, tell us what you want to do and what you can't figure out.

I think you should split your sentence to get a list of all words in it. 
Then, check if one of the words belongs to your list of "changeable" words ( inevitable, unavoidable, certain, sure) if so, replace it with the word you want ("necessary" in your example). 
But i'm not sure i understood your problem.

Comment: I asked that i want to create a dictionary/database in which i save different words against one word and my sentence get the words from that data base or file and replace it. –

Comment: the main thing I get input a sentence from user for example user give a input "the person age at least 18"
i use spacy library to break it and get tokens for whole sentence
the (article)
person (noun)
and so on 
after this i want to change some words like i want to change  "at least"--> "should be" ,In back end i have a text file in which i save many words against one word for example 
 'at least' , 'at most=should be, when user enter sentence and sentence have these words so it automatically change these words in to "should be."

Answer (score 0):

```
sen = "this is unavoidable that the kids must be 18"

words = sen.split()
new_words = []
for word in words:
    if word in ['inevitable', 'unavoidable', 'certain', 'sure']:
        word = 'necessary'
    new_words.append(word)

new_sen = " ".join(new_words)
print(new_sen)
```

Comment: thankyou but what if i want to change two word in a sentence?

Comment: and the second thing i want to ask that  i want to create a dictionary/database in which i save different words against one word and my sentence get  the words from that data base or file and replace it.